# How to crop an image in P5?

Tags: image, processing, crop, p5.js

[image]

I am working on a program in P5, an offshoot of Processing, that allows the user to upload an image, draw a line on top of the image, and then crop everything outside of the drawn shape out of the image.

[image: The green line jitters around on purpose]
(The green line jitters around on purpose)

I managed to get the points of the drawn line into an array, as well as make a shape out of these points. However, the cropping of the image is still a problem.

Processing has this functionality in vertex:
(https://processing.org/reference/vertex_.html)

However, I don't believe P5 has this functionality. I really don't want to have to convert the entire sketch into Processing. Is there any way to do this in P5, or to quickly convert this sketch into processing?

```javascript
// Make a variable to store the start image, as well as the drop image.
var img;

var cropX = [];
var cropY = [];
var pos = 25;
// Make an array for all paths.
var paths = [];

// Make a bool for whether or not I am painting.
var painting = false;

// Int for how long until drawing the next circle
var next = 10;

// Make vars for vectors that determine where the line is drawn.
var current;
var previous;

// Make ints for how much the lines dance around.
var shake = 10;
var minShake = shake * -1;
var maxShake = shake * 1;

// Make an int for the line thickness.
var thickness = 2;
var camera;
var tracing = false;

// Make vars to store the random values for colours into. 
var rc1;
var rc2;
var rc3;

// Variable for the framerate.
var fr;

// Variable that disables drawing lines when you didn't upload an image yet.
var tracing = false;


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


function preload() {

  //Load the starting image, and store it in img.
  img = loadImage("assets/startscreen.png");

  //Load the sound that plays when you export a screenshot.
  soundFormats('mp3');
  camera = loadSound('assets/camera.mp3');

}


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


function setup() {



  // Set the framerate so the lines don't jump about too quickly.
  fr = 20;

  // Setup a canvas
  var c = createCanvas(1680, 1050);

  // Store a random value out of 255 into the random colour values.
  rc1 = random(255);
  rc2 = random(255);
  rc3 = random(255);

  // Apply the right framerate
  frameRate(fr);

  // Add an event named drop, that runs function gotFile when a file is dropped onto the canvas
  c.drop(gotFile);

  // Store 0,0 vectors in current and previous.
  current = createVector(0, 0);
  previous = createVector(0, 0);

};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function draw() {


  // Colour the background dark grey.
  background(200);

  // Draw the loaded image at 0,0 coordinates.
image(img, 0, 0);



  //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


  // Count if I've been painting for longer than the 'next' variable.
  // Also check if tracing is enabled (if I've dropped an image or not).
  // If these are true I can draw a new line.
  if (millis() > next && painting && tracing) {

    // Grab mouse position and store it in variables mouseX and mouseY.  
    current.x = mouseX;
    current.y = mouseY;

    // Add new particle
    paths[paths.length - 1].add(current);

    // Update the 'next' variable, to allow itself 200 extra millisecond for drawing the actual line.
    next = millis() + 200;

    // Move the mouse values used to draw the end of the line
    // to a variable used to draw the start of the line,
    // so that the line is continuous.
    previous.x = current.x;
    previous.y = current.y;
    append(cropX, current.x);
    append(cropY, current.y);
  }

  // Make an integer called i, with a value of 0.
  // Add 1 to i for each item in the array paths.

  // Run this once for each item in the array.
  // Name each item in the array 'i' while working.
  // Display each item in the array.
  for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {

    // Update the current object in the array.
    paths[i].update();

    // Display each item in the array.
    paths[i].display();
  } 
  noStroke();
  noFill();
     beginShape();

     for (var i = 0; i < cropX.length; ++i) {
       vertex(cropX[i], cropY[i]);
     }
     endShape(CLOSE);


}


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

var ready = false;

// Make a function called gotFile, using the variable file.
function gotFile(file) {

  // Check if the dropped file is an image file
  if (file.type === 'image') {

    // Enable drawing lines.
    tracing = true;

    // if (ready) {
    //   img.remove();
    // }
    // Store the dropped image in the container which used to hold the startimage.
    img = createImg(file.data).style("opacity: 100; position: absolute; top: -10; right: -10; z-index: 100;draggable=false;");

    ready = true;

    // Error message in case not an image file.
  } else {
    println('Not an image file!');
  }
}


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function mouseWheel(event) {
  //event.delta can be +1 or -1 depending
  //on the wheel/scroll direction
  print(event.delta);
  //move the square one pixel up or down
  pos += event.delta;
  //uncomment to block page scrolling
  return false;
}

function mouseDragged() {
return false;
  }


// If left mousebutton is pressed down,
function mousePressed() {
  if (mouseButton == LEFT) {

    // set the variable counting when to place a new line to 0,
    next = 0;

    // set painting to true,
    painting = true;

    // store the mouse coordinates in mouseX and mouseY,
    previous.x = mouseX;
    previous.y = mouseY;

    // and add a new Path method to the array.
    paths.push(new Path());
  }
}

// When mouse is released, set painting to false, which disables any paths being drawn.
function mouseReleased() {
  painting = false;
}


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


// Describe the Path function that should be pushed to the array.
function Path() {

  // Create an array inside this function named particles.
  this.particles = [];
}

// Add the variable position to the function Path as its function'()' variable.
Path.prototype.add = function(position) {

  // Add a new particle to this particle array with a position and hue.
  this.particles.push(new Particle(position, this.hue));
}

// Take the Path() function, and and add this command to it.
Path.prototype.update = function() {

  // Make an integer called i, with a value of 0.
  // Add 1 to i for each item in the array paths.

  // Run this once for each item in the array.
  // Name each item in the array 'i' while working.
  // Display each item in the array.
  for (var i = 0; i < this.particles.length; i++) {
    this.particles[i].update();
  }
}

// Display the Path array.
Path.prototype.display = function() {

  // Loop through the array of particles backwards.
  for (var i = this.particles.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

    // Display each of these particles.
    this.particles[i].display(this.particles[i + 1]);

  }

}

// Particles along the path
function Particle(position, hue) {

  // Set the position of Particles to the mouseposition by creating a vector.
  this.position = createVector(position.x, position.y);
}

// Constantly update Particle.
Particle.prototype.update = function() {}

// Draw particle and connect it with a line
// Draw a line to another
Particle.prototype.display = function(other) {
  stroke(255, 255);

  // If we need to draw a line
  if (other) {
    stroke(rc1, rc2, rc3);
    strokeWeight(thickness);
    line(this.position.x + random(minShake, maxShake), this.position.y + random(minShake, maxShake), other.position.x + random(minShake, maxShake), other.position.y + random(minShake, maxShake));
  }
  if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW) && !camera.isPlaying()) {
    camera.play();
    save('myRemix.jpg');
    print(cropX);
    print(cropY)

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `vertex()` function you pointed out isn't cropping the image.

To crop an image, you probably want to use the [`PImage.mask()`](https://www.processing.org/reference/PImage_mask_.html) function. This lets you overlay a mask image overtop your original image so that only parts of your original image are visible.

You can also use a `PGraphics` instance as a mask image, so you can draw whatever mask you want. Here's a small example that creates a `PGraphics` mask consisting of an ellipse, then masks the original photo with that mask:

```java
PImage photo;
PGraphics maskImage;

void setup() {
  size(100, 100);
  photo = loadImage("pic.jpg");
  maskImage = createGraphics(photo.width, photo.height);


  maskImage.beginDraw();
  maskImage.background(0);
  maskImage.fill(255);
  maskImage.ellipseMode(RADIUS);
  maskImage.ellipse(photo.width/2, photo.height/2, 500, 500);
  maskImage.endDraw();

  photo.mask(maskImage);
}

void draw() {
  background(255, 0, 0);
  image(photo, 0, 0, width, height);
}
```

Your sketch would use a shape instead of an ellipse, but those are the basics.

Comment: @JordyvanLook No problem. Note that if an answer helped you, you can always mark it as accepted! :p